# ruby testing passes although it's wrong

Tags: ruby

i'm trying to follow the tutor and test my demo.

this is my code for testing

```
require_relative "../lib/team.rb"
require "minitest/autorun"
require "spec"

describe Team do
  it "has a name" do
  end
end
```

and this is my class

```
class Team
end
```

unexpectedly  when i run the test script in my terminal, the test passes successfully!
and display the following message

> 1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

but in the screencast the test fails with this error

> "Team has a name " #not yet implemented

Answer (score 2):

You aren't actually testing anything, so nothing is actually passing. (The result line shows that "0 assertions")

To get a failing test you need to create an assertion:

```
describe Team do
  it "has a name" do
    team = Team.new(name: "Mike")

    assert_equal team.name, "Mike"
  end
end
```